# How can I take a string and change the colour for each new line in TEXT?

Tags: matlab, text, colors, matlab-figure

To be more specific I have, for position `x`,`z` and `Y(1:size(y1,2))` is a list of strings (I think):

`text(x, z, Y(1:size(y1,2)));`.

I wish to colour in the different lines of `Y(1:size(y1,2)))`, which varies in size, in different colours. As this varies in size I cannot use the following method (as far as I am aware):

`text(x, z, {\color{magenta}Y(1),.. , \colour{red}Y(size(y1,2))}) %or similar`

Many Thanks!

Comment: This should be possible by using the Latex interpreter. But it seems to be tricky to use it. Take a look at the docs searching for text + Latex interpreter. Sorry, I dont have time to test it :(

Comment: I shall have a look at it. Thank you for the pointer.